# Moment timezone returning property 'preparse' of null

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

While trying to parse a certain date

```
moment('07/07/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY', 'Asia/Bangkok')
```

I receive the error **typeError: cannot read property 'preparse' of null**

http://jsfiddle.net/uq99udc9/7978/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [`moment.tz`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/) instead of [`moment(String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) since you are passing the timezone (`'Asia/Bangkok'`) parameter.

Your code could be like the following:

```
moment.tz('07/07/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY', 'Asia/Bangkok')
```

Here a working snippet based on the linked fiddle:

```js
$(function(){
  setInterval(function(){
    var divUtc = $('#divUTC');
    var divLocal = $('#divLocal');  
    //put UTC time into divUTC  
    divUtc.text(moment.utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));      
    
    //get text from divUTC and conver to local timezone  
    var localTime  = moment.utc(divUtc.text()).toDate();
    localTime = moment(localTime).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
    divLocal.text(localTime);  
      
    $('#divT').text(moment.tz('07/07/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY', 'Asia/Bangkok').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
  },1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.17/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>

UTC<br/>
<div id="divUTC"></div><br/>
Your Local Time with respect to above UTC time<br/>
<div id="divLocal">
</div>    
<br/>Thailand date time<br/>
<div id="divT">
</div>
```

Comment: Weird that it worked for me in the past. thank you very much the solution worked out.

Answer (score 0):

In case you observe this bug with nodejs, this is how to walk around it:

```
var moment = require('moment');
require('moment-timezone'); // important, if you remove this, it will crash
var mtz = moment.tz;
m=mtz("Mon Aug 22 23:32:59 +0000 2016", "ddd MMM DD HH:mm:ss Z YYYY", "UTC");
m.format("YYYY");
```